# reputation loss when down voting a spam Question

Tags: feature-request

Hi ,

when I voted down a spam question, my reputation was decreased by one.
I think after a question has been deleted due to spam, the reputation which was removed should be added back ;)

what do you think ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reputation will be restored next time your rep is recalculated. If you want to force this, you can go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and click the button at the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just flag it as spam? No need to downvote.

But I agree, when it is removed, your rep ought to be increased again.

Comment: +1; As a case study on flagging: I saw some spam on an SE site the other day that was voted as "-7" - if the first 4 of them had flagged as spam it would've joined my flag and it would've gone away on its own...

Comment: @Rowland That make me think, if a post goes below let's say -5 should subsequent downvoters be prompted "Is this post spam or offensive?" Going to post as a separate question.